# Publish subscribe pattern in jms for a financial application

Tags: java, design-patterns, jms, finance, subscriber

I am using a publish subscribe pattern in jms in order to implement trading feed in a financial application.However, the application requires feed data to be displayed without delay. This application I have written in java is not satisfying a constant and fast publishing rate and the application is lagging behind in displaying the feed data.The code for the publish subscribe pattern is the usual publish subscribe code one would write for any application in java.Is there a suggestion in order to facilitate faster publishers and to maintain a constant publish rate? Your comments are most appreciated.

Comment: If faster responses are necessary I would opt for a directer 'push' method from the Publisher end. Leaning more towards Web/Restful Services. (or direct services in case the receiving end is running in the same container) But it depends on how important these messages are to consider replacing JMS with a Service. You could always run these two side-by-side of course.

Comment: The publish and subscribe method is used from the MapsOperationCounter file of hazelcast...How should I make a director push ?

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me what the setup of your environment is.

- Hazelcast to distribute your data. (I'm not too familiar with Hazelcast)
- Publisher running in separate container. Linked to Hazelcast?
- Subscriber(s) Is it just one or are there many more linked to the publisher? Is it/Are they linked to Hazelcast?
- What kind of data is displayed? Some data/graphs in a web browser?

So why are you not using Hazelcast to push your data to the subscribers (instead of using JMS)? I see you have removed the reference to JMS from the original posting?

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions: ( they could be more specific if you had more details eg what broker you are using in the question )

- Is the JMS provider / broker configured to persist all messages to disk? If so, do you need guaranteed delivery for all messages? Requiring that all messages be persisted to disk will reduce your throughput to the low hundreds ( unless you have SSDs )
- Is your application running in the same JVM as the broker? Is the heap correctly sized? If the heap size is not well tuned, you could get lots of garbage collection pauses, which will kill performance.

Comment: Yes the JMS provider is configured to persist all messages to disk.Yes I need guaranteed delivery for all messages.No the application is not running on the same JVM as the broker.The application is a seperate glassfish domain than the main glassfish domain of the broker thus, they are different JVM's. Yes heap is correctly sized. I need to implement something in the code which will basically facilitate faster updating of data on the screen for the subscriber.